# What is G on Marketcap

Tags: currencies, market

I have checked the bitcoin marketcap charts on [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com). Looking at the charts I see time on the horizontal line and k, M and G on the vertical line.

What does G stand for?

Answer (score 1):

[Standard SI prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes). Kilo, Mega and G is for Giga, obviously. Just multiply the value with 10^9 to get the base value.